# Big arrow across the table (overlay)

Tags: arrows

As shown in picture, is there a way to achieve this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{rotating} % sidewaytables


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}



\begin{sidewaystable}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=|, right delimiter=|] {
    & K=3 & K=4 & K=5 & K=6 & K=7 & K=8 & K=9 & K=10 & K=11 & K=12\\
    \hline
    C=2 &4&7&10&12&14&16&18&20&&\\ \hline
    C=3 &4&7&11&16&21&24&27&30&&\\ \hline
    C=4 &4&7&11&16&22&29&36&40&&\\ \hline
    C=5 &4&7&11&16&22&29&37&46&&\\ \hline
    C=6 &4&7&11&16&22&29&37&46&&\\ \hline
    C=7 &4&7&11&16&22&29&37&46&&\\ \hline
    C=8 &4&7&11&16&22&29&37&46&&\\ \hline
    C=9 &4&7&11&16&22&29&37&46&&\\ \hline
    C=10&4&7&11&16&22&29&37&46&&\\
};
\draw[->,red,thick] (m-2-2.west) -- (m-2-3.east);
\draw[->,red,thick] (m-4-4.west) -- (m-4-7.east);
\draw[->,red,thick] (m-6-7.west) -- (m-6-8.east);
\draw[->,red,thick] (m-9-3.west) -- (m-9-6.east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{sidewaystable}


\end{document}
```

This works OK. But how do I make it into "tabular" look, ie the vertical lines that separates the columns.

Comment: For this the `tikzmark` macro seems to be the right way to go; I think a good starting point could be [cancelling out cells in tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86883/13304).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach uses `stackengine` package's `\topinset` macro to overlay the table with the arrows.  Perhaps a better arrow could be constructed... I just added a `\rightarrow` to the end of a long `\rule`.

The key to making the construction easy was reckoning the four lengths, `\cellv`, `\cellh`, `\vertoffset`, and `\horzoffset`.  Once that is done, the horizontal and vertical shifts for each arrow are integer multiples of `\cellh` and `\cellv`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,enumerate}
\usepackage{rotating} % sidewaytables
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newlength\cellv
\newlength\cellh
\newlength\vertoffset
\newlength\horzoffset
\setlength{\cellv}{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\cellh}{3.6em}
\setlength\vertoffset{.4\baselineskip}
\setlength\horzoffset{1.5em}
\def\stackalignment{l}
\newcommand\myarrow[1]{$\color{red}\rule[.47ex]{#1}{.6pt}\!\!\!\rightarrow$}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}

\[
\topinset{\myarrow{1.5\cellh}}{%
\topinset{\myarrow{3.5\cellh}}{%
\topinset{\myarrow{5.5\cellh}}{%
\(
    \begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
    & K=3 & K=4 & K=5 & K=6 & K=7 & K=8 & K=9 & K=10 & K=11 & K=12\\
    \hline
    C=2 &4&7&10&12&14&16&18&20&&\\ \hline
    C=3 &4&7&11&16&21&24&27&30&&\\ \hline
    C=4 &4&7&11&16&22&29&36&40&&\\ \hline
    C=5 &4&7&11&16&22&29&37&46&&\\ \hline
    C=6 &4&7&11&16&22&29&37&46&&\\ \hline
    C=7 &4&7&11&16&22&29&37&46&&\\ \hline
    C=8 &4&7&11&16&22&29&37&46&&\\ \hline
    C=9 &4&7&11&16&22&29&37&46&&\\ \hline
    C=10&4&7&11&16&22&29&37&46&&
    \end{array}
\)
}{1\cellv+\vertoffset}{3\cellh+\horzoffset}
}{2\cellv+\vertoffset}{5\cellh+\horzoffset}
}{3\cellv+\vertoffset}{7\cellh+\horzoffset}
\]
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just a note on stackengine package: I use MiKTeX and set to install new package on the fly. However, it does not seem to recognize it. Then I manually copied the stackengine.sty file to the folder. This time it askes for another .sty file, readarray.sty. and ect.

Which latex distribution are you using? or am I misunderstanding something about latex?

Comment: @ChenStatsYu Both packages, stackengine and readarray, are relatively new.  Both are available at ctan.org.  I presume they'll get picked up in a future release.  Sorry about that inconvenience.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{rotating} % sidewaytables


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}



\begin{sidewaystable}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,left delimiter=|, right delimiter=|] {
    & K=3 & K=4 & K=5 & K=6 & K=7 & K=8 & K=9 & K=10 & K=11 & K=12\\
    \hline
    C=2 &4&7&10&12&14&16&18&20&&\\ \hline
    C=3 &4&7&11&16&21&24&27&30&&\\ \hline
    C=4 &4&7&11&16&22&29&36&40&&\\ \hline
    C=5 &4&7&11&16&22&29&37&46&&\\ \hline
    C=6 &4&7&11&16&22&29&37&46&&\\ \hline
    C=7 &4&7&11&16&22&29&37&46&&\\ \hline
    C=8 &4&7&11&16&22&29&37&46&&\\ \hline
    C=9 &4&7&11&16&22&29&37&46&&\\ \hline
    C=10&4&7&11&16&22&29&37&46&&\\
};
\draw[->,red,thick] (m-2-2.west) -- (m-2-3.east);
\draw[->,red,thick] (m-4-4.west) -- (m-4-7.east);
\draw[->,red,thick] (m-6-7.west) -- (m-6-8.east);
\draw[->,red,thick] (m-9-3.west) -- (m-9-6.east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{sidewaystable}


\end{document}
```

This is another answer from a Chinese forum. 
However, I was not able to get it to a "tabular" look, ie the vertical lines that separates the columns.

Edit by Gonzalo Medina:

Here's how you can add the lines and shorten the arrow ends:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{rotating} % sidewaytables
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\tikzset{ 
table/.style={
  matrix of math nodes,
  row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={rectangle,draw=black,text width=3.3em,align=center},
  text depth=0.25ex,
  text height=2ex,
  nodes in empty cells
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [table] {
    & K=3 & K=4 & K=5 & K=6 & K=7 & K=8 & K=9 & K=10 & K=11 & K=12\\
    \hline
    C=2 &4&7&10&12&14&16&18&20&&\\ \hline
    C=3 &4&7&11&16&21&24&27&30&&\\ \hline
    C=4 &4&7&11&16&22&29&36&40&&\\ \hline
    C=5 &4&7&11&16&22&29&37&46&&\\ \hline
    C=6 &4&7&11&16&22&29&37&46&&\\ \hline
    C=7 &4&7&11&16&22&29&37&46&&\\ \hline
    C=8 &4&7&11&16&22&29&37&46&&\\ \hline
    C=9 &4&7&11&16&22&29&37&46&&\\ \hline
    C=10&4&7&11&16&22&29&37&46&&\\
};
\begin{scope}[shorten >= 10pt,shorten <= 10pt]
\draw[->,red,thick] (m-2-2.west) -- (m-2-3.east);
\draw[->,red,thick] (m-4-4.west) -- (m-4-7.east);
\draw[->,red,thick] (m-6-7.west) -- (m-6-8.east);
\draw[->,red,thick] (m-9-3.west) -- (m-9-6.east);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I edited your answer and added some code that will produce the lines you were needing; I also uploaded an image of the resulting table. I hope it's OK. If you don't like the edit, you can roll it back.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. That environment is similar to the classical environment `{tabualar}` but creates also PGF/TikZ nodes under the cells, rows and columns. It's possible to use these nodes to draw with TikZ whatever rule you want after the construction of the main array.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}

\begin{NiceTabular}{*{11}{c}}[hvlines-except-borders]
    & K=3 & K=4 & K=5 & K=6 & K=7 & K=8 & K=9 & K=10 & K=11 & K=12\\
    C=2 &4&7&10&12&14&16&18&20&&\\ 
    C=3 &4&7&11&16&21&24&27&30&&\\ 
    C=4 &4&7&11&16&22&29&36&40&&\\ 
    C=5 &4&7&11&16&22&29&37&46&&\\ 
    C=6 &4&7&11&16&22&29&37&46&&\\ 
    C=7 &4&7&11&16&22&29&37&46&&\\ 
    C=8 &4&7&11&16&22&29&37&46&&\\ 
    C=9 &4&7&11&16&22&29&37&46&&\\ 
    C=10&4&7&11&16&22&29&37&46&&\\
\Hline
\CodeAfter
\begin{tikzpicture} [->,red,thick,shorten > = -1mm, shorten < = -1mm]
   \draw (2-2.west) -- (2-3.east);
   \draw (4-4.west) -- (4-7.east);
   \draw (6-7.west) -- (6-8.east);
   \draw (9-3.west) -- (9-6.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]